# Better to use webview or Phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, android-webview

I just wanted to know which one is better and why? Apps like Quora, Facebook are native android app but they still load the web content but I don't think they use `PhoneGap`. So do they use `WebView`? Which one can be customized easily and which one is better? Because apps like Quora , Flipboard run really better. `Is there any other way to load web content in Android?`

Answer (score 2):

**PhoneGap** has its own usage, in case if from your web pages you want to use native features like camera, GPS or accelerometer then you should use PhoneGap as it provides API to use these feature using a JavaScriptInterface.

While **Webview** is base class on which you could add any functionality like start a spinner while page load starts or show a dialogbox when loading stops.

In short if your webpage doesn't need to access any native features of android then use a WebView and customise it using `setWebViewClient` and `setWebChromeClient` else `PhoneGap` serves you best with native features.

Comment: Let me know if you need more eloboration.

Comment: But apps like quora use webview and they can access any native features of android. And its very customizable too.

Comment: because they wrote their own javaScriptInterface to access native features. PhoneGap has API for all the native features. If you don't want access to all the features but only few of them, then even you can write your own javaScriptInterface that accesses only selected native features like we did in our app.

Comment: Oh ok. So PhoneGap is probably based on Webview and it provides the API which would to be too cumbersome to write for webview. Can you give some example or tutorial of writing my own javaScriptInterface? I just want to see how much customizable the webview is.

Comment: Also can you tell me any good app which implements Webview. I want to see how much customizable webView is.

Comment: this is a so primary example -https://github.com/scottagarman/Android-JavaScript-Interface-Example/blob/master/src/com/scottagarman/android/jsexample/JsExampleMain.java

Comment: you see all these apps facebook, instagram.. these apps use webview and native features as well.